# Jumps in Sobolev functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, continuity, lp-spaces, sobolev-spaces

Let's suppose $N\geq 2$. I know that functions in $W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ (with $p\leq N$) can be discontinous but all the examples that I know are **not** jump discontinuities (I've explained in the comments what I mean with jump discontinuities). Are there any examples of such discontinuities? And what about the case of a regular domain $\Omega\subseteq \mathbb{R}^N$ (a bounded open set with $C^1$ boundary)?

I've hard that Sobolev functions "don't like to jump", but I don't know any rigorous statement about this. Could you help me?

Comment: What do you mean by a jump discontinuity in higher dimensions? For example if $f=1_U$, the indicator function of an open set with smooth boundary, then $f$ has a weak derivative, but that derivative is a (vector) measure. In the case of $N=1$ this corresponds to a jump discontinuity essentially introducing a Dirac $\delta$ in the derivative.

Comment: I mean that there exist a $C^1$-differentiable hypersurface $M\subseteq \mathbb{R}^N$ (so that given a point $x_0\in M$ and given a sufficiently small ball $B_{x_0}$, the manifold $M$ splits the ball in two parts the left one and the right one), such that the limit of the function when $x\to x_0$ along a curve that approaches $x_0$ from the left is different from the limit of the function along a curve that approaches $x_0$ from the right for every $x_0\in  M$.

Comment: If you have a jump discontinuity, up to composition with a smooth function and cutoff, you should be able to reduced to the indicator function of a set. Then these functions can only be in $W^{s,p}$ if $s<1/p$ and so not in $W^{1,p}$.

Comment: How is this argumentation formalized?